# Android In/Out animated transitions without ViewFlipper

Tags: java, android

So I have a ActivityGroup, and I would like to animate the transition between its child activities.  Right now I have a "slide in from left" animation in XML that I am loading via AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation.

However this just animates the incoming activity.  I would like to slide the current activity out on the left side simultaneously.  I have been able to accomplish this with a ViewFlipper, but for this project it doesn't make sense to use this method.

What are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActivityGroup is deprecated. You should be using [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) instead. Animating fragments is easy. Just use the [setTransition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setTransition%28int%29) function when changing between them. If you're developing for an API Level that's less than 11, use the [Android Support Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I need this to be compatible with older versions of android.  Aren't fragments only applicable to API 11+?

Comment: just add the compatibility library to your project also called support library now. http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

Comment: Yea, sorry. I forgot to mention the android support package.

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  They should really mention this in the Fragments guide you linked to...